# WXPYTHON - How Do I Get Users Input in a MessageDialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets, wxpython

Here's my code:

```
def Quit(self, e):
    suremsg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Are you sure you want to close the program?","Are you sure?", wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION).ShowModal()

def Close(self):
    self.Close()
```

I'm technically wanting the program to close if the user clicks YES, and closes the MessageDialog and refuses to close if the user clicks NO.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I went for a little surf through many articles that explain how I can get the result of the user's input.

So, I switched my code to this:

```
   def Quit(self, e):
    suremsg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Are you sure you want to close the program?","Are you sure?", wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    result = suremsg.ShowModal()
    if result == wx.ID_YES:
       self.Close()
    else:
       suremsg.Destroy()
```

And it worked like a charm!